# Can we add support for diff syntax highlighting?

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Can we add support for diff syntax highlighting?

For example, the following should have syntax color highlighting:

````
```diff
-   spec_version: 9270,
+   spec_version: 9280,
```
````

Answer (score 0):

that would be nice. `js` as well would be helpful I suspect if there's not a hook for that specifically.

Comment: This is already supported: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/tags/javascript/info

You can see it already all over the forum.

Answer (score 0):

`diff` is not a supported "highlighted syntax" on StackExchange.

You can find the complete list here: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)

So it does not seem like something we can add, without having it be added all the way at the top of the StackExchange platform.